# Repeated clicks on iframe don't register as clicks

Tags: html, iframe, click

I'm using the following code in order to check when the user clicks a (cross-domain) iframe:

```
var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

I'm using this to check if a user clicked a Google Ad, and it works fine the first time you click it. However the second click on the banner doesn't get registered (unless you refresh the page again).

What I've noticed, though, is that if I click anywhere OUTSIDE the iframe after the first click, and then I click the banner again, the click gets registered.

What I tried to do was use 'window.focus();' on mouseover, but it doesn't fix it.

Can you help me?

Comment: You are listening for your window to blur or lose focus. So it works the first time because your window had focus and lost it, but then the second time, the iframe already had focus and the window did not have focus, so no event was fired.

Comment: Well, isn't there a fix for that? Why doesn't doing 'window.focus();' work?